# Calculating management fees paid during the last 12 months

Tags: finance

I'm looking for a way to calculate the total management fees paid by a customer during the last 12-months.

I'm taking the following assumptions:

- The total accumulation as of today is A
- The monthly deposit is D
- There are deposit fees calculated based on the amount deposited every month - F1
- There are accumulation fees calculated yearly (I guess) based on the total accumulation - F2 (I'm not sure if these fees are calculated every month based on the total accumulation at the end of every month or at the end of the year)